# Integrating azure data factory and airflow

Tags: azure, airflow, azure-data-factory

My end goal is to run Azure data factory (ADF) pipelines using Airflow. My current setup is a docker file which has python packages required for this like azure data providers and a helm chart from apache airflow. I have a custom values.yaml with celery executor which I am upgrading every time to run airflow locally.

So far this part is success.

The python packages give an azure data factory option just like how I wanted but I am unable to validate these. I tested the same credentials (resource group, client id, client secret, tenant id, subscription id) using a python code and it is valid.

This doesn't work on Airflow and I see this error

```
*** Trying to get logs (last 100 lines) from worker pod azuredatafactoryrunpipeline.3f394072d09e4c6e8d59566776f18b78 ***
```

```
*** Unable to fetch logs from worker pod azuredatafactoryrunpipeline.3f394072d09e4c6e8d59566776f18b78 ***
(404)
Reason: Not Found
```

```
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '4a506d8b-9bac-44d8-8a7c-ee01810e478f', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Mon, 07 Feb 2022 22:05:52 GMT', 'Content-Length': '288'})
```

```
HTTP response body: b'{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods \\"azuredatafactoryrunpipeline.3f394072d09e4c6e8d59566776f18b78\\" not found","reason":"NotFound","details":{"name":"azuredatafactoryrunpipeline.3f394072d09e4c6e8d59566776f18b78","kind":"pods"},"code":404}\n'
```

How do I debug this?

Is there a way to test ADF connection from Airflow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow has `AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator` which used to execute a pipeline within a data factory (see [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/operators/adf_run_pipeline.html))

You can also add sensor to wait till the pipeline is finished before continuing execution of your Airflow workflow.

Usage example:

```
from airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.operators.data_factory import AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator
from airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.sensors.data_factory import AzureDataFactoryPipelineRunStatusSensor

run_pipeline1 = AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator(
    task_id="run_pipeline",
    pipeline_name="pipeline",
    parameters={"myParam": "value"},
)

pipeline_run_sensor = AzureDataFactoryPipelineRunStatusSensor(
    task_id="pipeline_run_sensor",
    run_id=run_pipeline.output["run_id"],
)
run_pipeline2 >> pipeline_run_sensor
```

To define ADF connection in Airflow check this [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/connections/adf.html).

Comment: How do I define a pipeline which is a folder on ADF? from your snippet, what should I do if "pipeline" is in a folder called "main"

```run_pipeline1 = AzureDataFactoryRunPipelineOperator(
    task_id="run_pipeline",
    pipeline_name="main\pipeline",
    parameters={"myParam": "value"},
)
```

giving as main\pipeline wouldn't work.

Comment: You should be able to trigger by name regardless of the path